# How to loop through array and do something different with the last index?

Tags: ios, swift

So, I have an array of `Genre` objects that contain `name` properties that are `Strings` that I want a `UILabel.text` to contain the values.

Id like the label to look something like this ultimately:

String[0] / String[1] / String[2] / String[3]

with the front slashes separating the strings. I can get the label to contain the values, and I can even get the / separators, but my logic is flawed as after the last string I still get the front slash.

Can someone help me with the logic where it will add the string and a front slash unless its the last item in the array and if its the last item in the array it should just add the string and no front slash.

Right now I just have a simple For In loop

```
if game?.genres?[0].name == nil {

for genre in game!.genres! {
    genreLabel.text! += "\(genre.name!) / "
    }
}
```

Ive tried 
`game.genres.map { $0.name }.joined(separator: “ / “)`

but that gives an error of:
`Value of type '[Genre]' has no member 'name'`

What is the logic here to do something different with the last element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't use enough questions marks, the compiler thinks you're using [Optional.map](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=swift%20optional%20mapo&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safari_group=9) instead of [Array.map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map).

You can get the result you want, like this:

```swift
game?.genres?.compactMap(\.name).joined(separator: " / ")
```

…but you're using too many optionals. Just make `genres` non-optional. An array can already be empty. It doesn't also need to be `nil`.

```swift
game?.genres.compactMap(\.name).joined(separator: " / ")
```

…and if you can, make `game` and `name` non-optional too.

```swift
game.genres.map(\.name).joined(separator: " / ")
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by using index

```
for (index,genre) in game!.genres!.enumerated() {
    genreLabel.text! += "\(genre.name!) / "
    if index == game!.genres!.count -1 {
       // do something with last index
    }
}
```

Comment: Id like to add this worked, however I chose the other answer due to the simplicity of it.